# What is the meaning of this syntax, relating to c++

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

```
return int_length(len > 0 ? len : 1)
```

what is the meaning of the syntax in the brackets, I keep getting confused when reading this code.
thanks

Comment: Ternary operator: [ternary wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) - a very condensed if-else.

Comment: why the serial downvoting?

Comment: @Daniel, apparently somebody's thinking that answering a duplicate deserves downvotes. (Hint: it usually does not.)

Comment: Off-topic: It's interesting how _I_ got notified of the previous comment by Frédéric Hamidi. @DanielA.White, where you notified, too?

Comment: Everything was being downvoted that was correct.... strange.

Comment: @DanielDaranas i was. i guess its some regex.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the correct term is "conditional operator". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257229/what-are-these-called#comment3367165_3257229 :)

Comment: It's also damned silliness here.  Why not `return int_length(max(len, 1))`?  Yes, I know a `using` statement is needed for that.  But wouldn't that be clearer?

Comment: @Eric, what `using`? Just write `std::max()`.

Answer (score 4):

It is a ternary operator. If `len>0` is true result of the expression is `len` else its `1`.

`if(len > 0)` it will return `int_length(len);`

else it will return `int_length(1);`

Answer (score 3):

That's the ternary operator.

It's equivalent to

```
if (len>0)
    return int_length(len);
else
    return int_length(1);
```

Comment: Why the -1 on this? Upvoting.

Comment: why -1 on all correct answers? wtf..

Comment: Because they're not strictly speaking correct.  In this case, the answer gives something equivalent to the complete statement; the poster asked about the actual expression that was an argument to `int_length`.  (Not that I think that's an valid reason to downvote, but it's the only criticism I can think of.)

Answer (score 2):

it means

```
if(len > 0)
{
   return int_length(len);
}
else
{  
   return int_length(1);
}
```

Comment: Except that it's an order of magnitude more readable.

Answer (score 1):

That is the ternary conditional operator. Its an "inline if".

It basically is this

```
int temp;
if (len > 0)
{
  temp = len;
}
else
{
  temp = 1;
}

int_length(temp);
```